# Spring - @Scheduled NullPointer @Autowired property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I using Spring Boot 4.

I am trying to schedule a task, but when I retrieve information from the DB I get this error:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   [model.User#2] - no Session   at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:169)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]

The problem is when I retrieve information from the database, two parameters of type User that is another table of the DB get this error:

> com.sun.jdi.InvocationException: Exception occurred in target VM
>   occurred invoking method.

[Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw1DN.png)

This its my code:

### Scheduled Class

```
@Component
public class StartupApplicationListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartupApplicationListener.class);

    @Autowired
    public BlockService blockService;

    @Autowired
    public TransactionService transactionService;

    @Autowired
    public WalletService walletService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000, initialDelay=1) // (cron="0 0 * * *")
    public void findUser() throws InterruptedException {
        TransactionUtils tu = new TransactionUtils();

        tu.startTransactions(blockService, transactionService, walletService);
    }

}
```

### Utils Class

public void startTransactions(BlockService blockService2, TransactionService transactionService2,
        WalletService walletService2) {

```
Block lastBlock = blockService2.getLastBlock();

List<Transaction> transactions = transactionService2.listAll();

for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
    Block newBlock = Utils.generateBlock(transaction, lastBlock);
    doTransaction(transaction, newBlock, lastBlock, walletService2);
    transactionService.delete(transaction.getId());
    transactions.remove(transaction);
}
```

### Transaction Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    public int quantity;

    @Column(name = "message")
    public String message;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sender_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    public User sender;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    public User receiver;

    public Transaction() {

    }

    //Getter & Setter....
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you added `@EnableScheduling` annotation to your spring boot application class?

Comment: Yes, 
@hrdkisback

Comment: Your question is about a `NullPointerException`. according to the title, but it isn't. Please fix the title or the question to match this.

Comment: either [The best way to handle `LazyInitializationException`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/) will help you or you need to paste more code :)

Comment: When you get 'transaction transactionService2.listAll()' use in implementation of rhis method join fetch with 'User receiver'.

Comment: you've set fetch type to the lazy. so user not loaded immediately. likely after you back from transaction method you call getUser(). while your transaction and session closed so it's no transaction to execute getUser query